# Sudoers and setfacl command with arguments (:, " chars)

Tags: linux, sudo

in a case of a deployment script (https://github.com/EasyCorp/easy-deploy-bundle/blob/master/doc/default-deployer.md#security-options) I need to run `setfacl` from a distant machine that push code.

To do that in the sudoer file I've add for a specific user the right to run the command without password, but I would like do it for a full command:

```
username  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/setfacl setfacl -RL -m u:"www-data":rwX var/cache/ var/log/
```

At the moment I'm forced to remove arguments of the command, because the full command is rejected. I've tried to add a `\` to escape `:`, the same for `"`. But it don't work.

```
username  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/setfacl setfacl
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`setfacl` is the same as `/usr/bin/setfacl`. Prefer the later. Don't write both though.

You're right, to escape `:` the prefix is `\`.

To specify multiple paths, you must repeat the command by using a comma as a separator. You could also duplicate the whole line. It's up to you.

The end result should looks like:

`username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/setfacl -RL -m u\:www-data\:rwX var/cache, /usr/bin/setfacl -R -m u\:www-data\:rwX var/log`